# Oracle: Consolidate rows

Tags: oracle

I just stumbled across a problem I'm unfortunately not able to solve myself.

Situation:
I have a DB table which contains a full history of data, e.g. products. Every time an attribute (field) of the product changes, a new record is created and inserted into this table.
For now, I only want to take a look at status change events.

Sample:

```
PRODUCT_ID VALID_FROM          VALID_TO            STATUS
========   =================== =================== ======
08154711   09.07.2004 08:12:00 27.10.2005 08:00:00 STAT1
08154711   27.10.2005 08:01:00 24.05.2007 10:56:00 STAT1
08154711   24.05.2007 10:57:00 25.05.2007 12:20:00 STAT2
08154711   25.05.2007 12:21:00 30.05.2007 11:11:00 STAT2
08154711   30.05.2007 11:12:00 25.06.2007 09:49:00 STAT2
08154711   25.06.2007 09:50:00 25.06.2007 11:02:00 STAT1
08154711   25.06.2007 11:03:00 17.07.2007 09:28:00 STAT1
08154711   17.07.2007 09:29:00 02.09.2008 10:49:00 STAT1
08154711   02.09.2008 10:50:00 01.04.2010 07:56:00 STAT1
08154711   01.04.2010 07:57:00 06.04.2010 13:43:00 STAT2
```

Result should be like this:

```
PRODUCT_ID VALID_FROM          VALID_TO            STATUS
========   =================== =================== ======
08154711   09.07.2004 08:12:00 24.05.2007 10:56:00 STAT1
08154711   24.05.2007 10:57:00 25.06.2007 09:49:00 STAT2
08154711   25.06.2007 09:50:00 01.04.2010 07:56:00 STAT1
08154711   01.04.2010 07:57:00 06.04.2010 13:43:00 STAT2
```

Meaning just consolidate all "blocks" and taking MIN(VALID_FROM) and MAX(VALID_TO) for each block.

Is this at all possible with SQL or is doing it within a function the only way it can be acomplished?

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: In your sample, what are your rows ordered by?

Comment: And is your `product_id` always the same?  Is it part of what you define as a "block"  (product_id/status)?

Comment: The sample data is from only one of the products in the database. So PRODUCT_ID always is the same. Data is ordered by PRODUCT_ID, VALID_FROM ASC. A "block" is all rows with the same status until there is a status switch which marks the beginning of the next block. And of course if it is a new product a new block starts, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  WITH w_data AS (
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('09.07.2004 08:12:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('27.10.2005 08:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('27.10.2005 08:01:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('24.05.2007 10:56:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('24.05.2007 10:57:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.05.2007 12:20:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.05.2007 12:21:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('30.05.2007 11:11:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('30.05.2007 11:12:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.06.2007 09:49:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.06.2007 09:50:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.06.2007 11:02:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.06.2007 11:03:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('17.07.2007 09:28:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('17.07.2007 09:29:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('02.09.2008 10:49:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('02.09.2008 10:50:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('01.04.2010 07:56:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
           select '08154711' product_id, to_date('01.04.2010 07:57:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('06.04.2010 13:43:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual
           ),
        w_grp1 as (
           select product_id, valid_from, valid_to, status,
                  case when status = lag(status) over (partition by product_id order by valid_from, valid_to)
                       then 0 else 1 end grps
             from w_data
           ),
        w_groups as (
           select product_id, valid_from, valid_to, status,
                   sum(grps) over (partition by product_id order by valid_from, valid_to) grp_id
             from w_grp1
           ),
        w_sub as (
           select product_id,
                    first_value(valid_from) over 
                       (partition by product_id, grp_id order by valid_from,      valid_to     ) valid_from,
                    first_value(valid_to)   over 
                       (partition by product_id, grp_id order by valid_from desc, valid_to desc) valid_to,
                    first_value(status)     over 
                       (partition by product_id, grp_id order by valid_from,      valid_to     ) status,
                    row_number() over (partition by product_id, grp_id order by valid_from, valid_to) rn
             from w_groups
           )
  select product_id, valid_from, valid_to, status
    from w_sub
   where rn = 1
  /

  PRODUCT_ VALID_FROM           VALID_TO             STATU
  -------- -------------------- -------------------- -----
  08154711 09-jul-2004 08:12:00 24-may-2007 10:56:00 STAT1
  08154711 24-may-2007 10:57:00 25-jun-2007 09:49:00 STAT2
  08154711 25-jun-2007 09:50:00 01-apr-2010 07:56:00 STAT1
  08154711 01-apr-2010 07:57:00 06-apr-2010 13:43:00 STAT2

  4 rows selected.
```

Explanation:

Run the query 1 "layer" at a time to see what it's doing and it should become pretty obvious what's going on.

w_data is just a setup for your sample data .

w_grp1 is used to to pinpoint the first member of each "group" .. which I'm assuming to be when the Status for this record is different than the status for the previous record (LAG).

w_groups when uses a windowing sum analytic to create the actual "grp_id"s we can use as groups later.

w_sub is just a "sub-total" kind of logic as I pick out the values from the rows you want (ie the First valid_from date, the Last valid_to date, etc.)
Note that the Last date is picked using FIRST_VALUE and a DESC order by ;)  (try it with LAST_VALUE and see what happens .. it won't work the way you want ;) )
Also, at this point, we use the "rn" column to number the rows of each group, so we can later pick out just the first one.

The final query just picks out the first row of each "group" .. giving you the final result.

Comment: Thank you Ditto! When having it right on the screen it looks quite easy ... think I have to take a closer look at all those analytic functions now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that for a given product_id there are no gaps between the previous row's valid_to and the next row's valid_from, then you could use the [tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) method to generate the groups:

```
with sample_data as (select '08154711' product_id, to_date('09.07.2004 08:12:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('27.10.2005 08:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('27.10.2005 08:01:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('24.05.2007 10:56:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('24.05.2007 10:57:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.05.2007 12:20:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.05.2007 12:21:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('30.05.2007 11:11:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('30.05.2007 11:12:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.06.2007 09:49:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.06.2007 09:50:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.06.2007 11:02:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.06.2007 11:03:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('17.07.2007 09:28:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('17.07.2007 09:29:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('02.09.2008 10:49:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('02.09.2008 10:50:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('01.04.2010 07:56:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('01.04.2010 07:57:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('06.04.2010 13:43:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual),
     tabibitosan as (select product_id,
                            valid_from,
                            valid_to,
                            status,
                            row_number() over (partition by product_id order by valid_from)
                              - row_number() over (partition by product_id, status order by valid_from) grp
                     from   sample_data)
select   product_id,
         min(valid_from) valid_from,
         max(valid_to) valid_to,
         status
from     tabibitosan
group by product_id,
         status,
         grp
order by product_id,
         valid_from;


PRODUCT_ID VALID_FROM            VALID_TO              STATUS
---------- --------------------- --------------------- ------
08154711   09/07/2004 08:12:00   24/05/2007 10:56:00   STAT1 
08154711   24/05/2007 10:57:00   25/06/2007 09:49:00   STAT2 
08154711   25/06/2007 09:50:00   01/04/2010 07:56:00   STAT1 
08154711   01/04/2010 07:57:00   06/04/2010 13:43:00   STAT2
```

---

Here is a modified version of sstan's answer that will, I think, both match the OP's requirements and take account of breaks in the data:

```
with sample_data as (select '08154711' product_id, to_date('09.07.2004 08:12:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('27.10.2005 08:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('27.10.2005 08:01:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('24.05.2007 10:56:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('24.05.2007 10:57:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.05.2007 12:20:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.05.2007 12:21:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('30.05.2007 11:11:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('30.05.2007 11:12:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.06.2007 09:49:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.06.2007 09:50:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('25.06.2007 11:02:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('25.06.2007 11:03:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('17.07.2007 09:28:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('17.07.2007 09:29:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('02.09.2008 10:49:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('02.09.2008 10:50:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('01.04.2010 07:56:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '08154711' product_id, to_date('01.04.2010 07:57:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('06.04.2010 13:43:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '11111111' product_id, to_date('10.07.2004 10:42:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('21.10.2005 14:35:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '11111111' product_id, to_date('21.10.2005 14:36:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('24.11.2005 16:18:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '11111111' product_id, to_date('01.01.2006 06:45:14','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('03.01.2006 07:56:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual union all
                     select '11111111' product_id, to_date('03.01.2006 07:57:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('01.04.2010 07:59:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '11111111' product_id, to_date('01.04.2010 08:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('04.07.2010 13:05:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT2' status from dual union all
                     select '11111111' product_id, to_date('04.07.2010 13:06:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_from, to_date('01.09.2011 07:50:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') valid_to, 'STAT1' status from dual),
             res as (select product_id,
                            valid_from,
                            valid_to,
                            status,
                            lag(valid_to) over (partition by product_id order by valid_from) prev_valid_to,
                            lag(status) over (partition by product_id order by valid_from) as prev_status
                     from   sample_data),
       final_res as (select product_id,
                            valid_from,
                            valid_to,
                            status,
                            sum(case when valid_from - prev_valid_to = 1/(24*60)
                                            and status = prev_status
                                          then 0 
                                     else 1
                                end) over (partition by product_id order by valid_from) as grouping_id
                     from   res)
select   product_id,
         min(valid_from) as valid_from,
         max(valid_to) as valid_to,
         status
from     final_res
group by grouping_id,
         product_id,
         status
order by product_id,
         grouping_id;

PRODUCT_ID VALID_FROM            VALID_TO              STATUS
---------- --------------------- --------------------- ------
08154711   09/07/2004 08:12:00   24/05/2007 10:56:00   STAT1 
08154711   24/05/2007 10:57:00   25/06/2007 09:49:00   STAT2 
08154711   25/06/2007 09:50:00   01/04/2010 07:56:00   STAT1 
08154711   01/04/2010 07:57:00   06/04/2010 13:43:00   STAT2 
11111111   10/07/2004 10:42:00   24/11/2005 16:18:00   STAT1 
11111111   01/01/2006 06:45:14   03/01/2006 07:56:00   STAT1 
11111111   03/01/2006 07:57:00   04/07/2010 13:05:00   STAT2 
11111111   04/07/2010 13:06:00   01/09/2011 07:50:00   STAT1
```

If there are never going to be any gaps between the rows for a given product id, then I would suggest the original tabibitosan answer would be more efficient, as it only needs one set of analytic queries, vs the two required in sstan's modified answer.

Comment: Hey Thanks! For all the analytics I use and know, I still keep forgetting this "row_number() - row_number()" trick to generate groups .. ;)  Thanks for the reminder ... (I suspect this might just run smoother overall than mine as well - less subqueries - not really sure though ... )

Comment: @Ditto As with everything, the OP should test all the solutions against their dataset and pick the one that works best.

Comment: @Ditto (I actually think a modified version of sstan's answer would be the most robust solution, as mine won't take account of gaps between the rows for a given product_id. I was hoping they'd update their answer, but they haven't as yet, so I think I'll go ahead and update it in mine.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a few assumptions that are not immediately clear in your post:

- The order of the rows is determined by the `valid_from` value.
- *"blocks"* are defined as consecutive rows with the same `product_id/status` value combination.

If so, the following query uses a combination of `lag` and a cumulative sum to create *"blocks"* that you can then `group by` to get the results.

```
select product_id,
       min(valid_from) as valid_from,
       max(valid_to) as valid_to,
       status
  from (select product_id,
               valid_from,
               valid_to,
               status,
               sum(case when product_id = prev_product_id and status = prev_status
                        then 0 else 1 end) over (order by valid_from) as grouping_id
          from (select product_id,
                       lag(product_id) over (order by valid_from) as prev_product_id,
                       valid_from,
                       valid_to,
                       status,
                       lag(status) over (order by valid_from) as prev_status
                  from table_name))
 group by grouping_id, product_id, status
 order by grouping_id
```

Comment: You're missing the "partition by product_id" in the analytic functions; plus, if you did a check for the previous valid_to is consecutive with the current valid_from in the sum()'s case statement, you would have something that catered for non-consecutive blocks with the same status. But for that, I'd upvote this answer *{:-)

Comment: @Boneist: You may be right.  It's just hard to tell exactly what OP wants based on the very limited sample he provided.  Different `product_id`s with expected results would clarify things.  With the sample provided, my query returns the right results as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7888

Comment: For sure, it does; it's just it could be even better - and more flexible than the tabibitosan method I proposed!